# VSCode Intergrated Terminal Issue

Tags: visual-studio-code

Added a custom font family to use in my VSCode, and now the Right Click -> Open In Integrated Terminal function opens all of my projects in the default Powershell. It was working properly opening everything in Git Bash as the default up until the font was added.
Can anyone identify the issue? I still have Git Bash as my default profile as well.

```
{
    "open-in-browser.default": "Google Chrome",
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        
        "Bash": {
            "path": "bash",
            "args": [
                "-l"
            ],
            "icon": "terminal-bash"
        },
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash"
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {

        "bash": {
            "path": "bash",
            "args": [
                "-l"
            ],
            "icon": "terminal-bash"
        },
        "zsh": {
            "path": "zsh",
            "args": [
                "-l"
            ]
        },
        "fish": {
            "path": "fish",
            "args": [
                "-l"
            ]
        },
        "tmux": {
            "path": "tmux",
            "icon": "terminal-tmux"
        },
        "pwsh": {
            "path": "pwsh",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows":  "Git Bash",
    "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
}
```

Comment: I've discovered that the terminal change in settings only goes into effect after VS Code is restarted. So you may try setting it to Git Bash in the Settings UI, and then restart VS code (make sure to close all windows).

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue where I have Git Bash set as my default but when I right click a file in the explorer to open in integrated terminal, it opens in Powershell.

Try adding this path to the Git Bash property in "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows" :

```
 "Git Bash": {
  "path": ["C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"],
   "source": "Git Bash"
 }
```

This only fixed opening a new terminal in Git Bash when using Ctrl + `, (not the right click -> open in new terminal) but maybe it will work for you. Maybe there's a bug in a recent VS Code update.